# How can I make a controller for this JSON request with four multiparts along with fields

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, file-upload

I want to make a controller for accepting multiparts as well as form data.

Do I have to accept  all data in DTOs or do I have to accept multiparts separately?

```
    {
     "isTRCAvailable": false,
    "trcApplicableFrom": "2019-06-19T15:30:33.956Z",
    "trcApplicableTo": "2019-06-19T15:30:33.956Z",
    "trcFile": null,
    "isTenFAvailable": false,
    "tenFApplicableFrom": "2019-06-19T15:30:33.956Z",
    "tenFApplicableTo": "2019-06-19T15:30:33.956Z",
    "tenFFile": null,

    "weatherPEInIndia": false,
    "wpeApplicableFrom": "2019-06-19T15:30:33.956Z",
    "wpeApplicableTo": "2019-06-19T15:30:33.956Z",
    "wpeFile": null,

    "noPEDocumentAvaliable": false,
    "noPEFile": null,
}
```

Comment: How would you like to work with that data afterwards? Will you need to use every single piece of data in there? I recommend using a DTO with a @RequestBody annotation.

Comment: yes i need to use all the data in dto.

Comment: can i accept json data as a string?

Comment: Yes, as long as you are sending it as a JSON request body via a post, for example, and the DTO is prepared to decode those attribute values, you should be fine.

Comment: actually i am accepting json data as a string and multiparts separately in api. it is working in postman but it is not working when i am trying to request from angular it is causing 400. this was surprising to me.

Comment: Are you sure angular is encoding the string into a correct JSON format? Are you sure it is making the correct request (POST)? Are you sure it is sending the string as the body of the request, and not a parameter?

Comment: Sorry but asking about angular is a whole other question on the forum... Did you solve your primary question with our help on spring?

Comment: yes it got solved from spring prospective.

Comment: So please consider upvoting the help you have got so that more people can access it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `@JsonUnwrapped` and `@JsonProperty`. For example:

```
public class EmbeddedData {

    @JsonProperty("ApplicableFrom")
    Date applicableFrom;

    @JsonProperty("ApplicableTo")
    Date applicableTo;

    @JsonProperty("File")
    Object file;

    .....
}

public class Data {

    Boolean isTRCAvailable;

    @JsonUnwrapped(prefix = "trc")
    EmbeddedData trc;

    Boolean isTenFAvailable;

    @JsonUnwrapped(prefix = "tenF")
    EmbeddedData tenF;

    Boolean weatherPEInIndia;

    @JsonUnwrapped(prefix = "wpe")
    EmbeddedData wpe;

    .....
}
```

Comment: how i can use these annotations ?